# How to record all player actions in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to work out a way to record all actions a player makes in minecraft, including moving, stopping moving, changing direction, placing a block (and block location/type), breaking a block (and block location/type), eating, pushing buttons, pulling levers, opening doors, attacking mobs (being hit by mobs) etc.

I've looking for a minecraft API but this doesn't exist yet! Is there any way to do this at the moment?

Comment: In minecraft or as a mod?

Comment: Either would be great.

Comment: What do you need this data for?

Comment: Well there's a few things I want to play around with. First off I just want to record every action, so I can compare different people (for example: you break more blocks, but I find more iron)

Comment: Then this would be more suited as a mod than with commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option I know of is the Instant Replay project by Sethbling that can be found [here](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=17AUbVnpc9g). The map is available for download in the video description so you can use that code or parts of it. 
However, you sound as if you're looking for a mod and this project relies entirely on command blocks, so this may not be what you really want.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, but it's a good start, thanks!

Comment: That's great! Also you could use data that is already pre-recorded and assign them to scoreboard objectives. I forgot to mention this earlier, but I want to provide you with what I can.